# python max function in mysql for substrings

Tags: python, mysql

I was wondering if this is possible with MySQL. I need some help on doing this with MySQL.

Here is the python code

```
def getID(episode_id,seperator = "_"):
    x = episode_id.split(seperator)
    sep_id = max(x, key=len)
    return sep_id

print getID("AK0033_A")
```

Comment: at the moment this seems to work.
`code`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('ANA_AK0033_A', '_', 2);`code` But if i have a longer id with more underscores i am not sure if it will work.

Comment: This seems to be working.`code`select substring_index('ANA_AK0033_ENG_A','_',(LENGTH('ANA_AK0033_ENG_A') - LENGTH(REPLACE('ANA_AK0033_ENG_A', '_', ''))) / LENGTH('_'));`code`

Comment: Now with this added to my database as a stored procedure, can i group by this procedure?

Comment: If this is the _same_ question, please _edit_ your post. If this is a _new_ question, please _ask_ a new question.